# Trying to use Android internal storage for a high score array.

Tags: java, android, eclipse, andengine

Using this link 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

I am trying to build a high scores array for an app game. I want to store this internally. I have just started and I'm getting errors I can't figure out. I just wanted to test to make sure it does create the file. I am using Eclipse with Java code and andEngine. Please help!!

**My errors are:
The method openFileOutput(String, int) is undefined for the type GameScene
Syntax error on token "write", Identifier expected after this token**

```js
package com.example.game;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Timer;

import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.camera.hud.HUD;
import org.andengine.engine.handler.timer.ITimerCallback;
import org.andengine.engine.handler.timer.TimerHandler;
import org.andengine.entity.Entity;
import org.andengine.entity.IEntity;
import org.andengine.entity.modifier.DelayModifier;
import org.andengine.entity.primitive.Rectangle;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.IOnSceneTouchListener;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.Background;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.ParallaxBackground;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.ParallaxBackground.ParallaxEntity;
import org.andengine.entity.sprite.Sprite;
import org.andengine.entity.text.Text;
import org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.FixedStepPhysicsWorld;
import org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsFactory;
import org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.PhysicsWorld;
import org.andengine.extension.physics.box2d.util.Vector2Pool;
import org.andengine.input.sensor.acceleration.AccelerationData;
import org.andengine.input.sensor.acceleration.IAccelerationListener;
import org.andengine.input.sensor.orientation.IOrientationListener;
import org.andengine.input.sensor.orientation.OrientationSensorOptions;
import org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent;
import org.andengine.util.color.Color;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;


import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.FixtureDef;
import com.example.game.SceneManager.SceneType;



public class GameScene extends BaseScene implements IAccelerationListener
{
 

     public IAccelerationListener yo;
 public static PhysicsWorld physicsWorld;  
     private float tiltSpeedX;
     private float tiltSpeedY;
     private int collisionCheck=0;
 
 private HUD gameHUD;
 private Text scoreText;
 private Text enemyLife;
 
 float accelerometerSpeedX;
 
 private int lives=3;
 private int captainLives=3;

 
    
 private Player player;
 private Captain captain;
 private Crab crab;
 private Bomb bomb;
 private Princess princess;
 
 Sprite explosion;
 Sprite heart;
 Sprite explosion2;
 int flag = 1;
 int flag2 = 1;
 int flag3 = 1;
 
 private void createHUD()
 {
     gameHUD = new HUD();
     engine.enableAccelerationSensor(activity, this);
     // CREATE SCORE TEXT
     scoreText = new Text(20, 420, resourcesManager.font, "Lives: 0123456789", vbom);
     scoreText.setSkewCenter(0, 0);    
     scoreText.setText("Lives: "+ lives);
     gameHUD.attachChild(scoreText);
     
     enemyLife = new Text(600, 20, resourcesManager.font, "Enemy: 0123456789", vbom);
     enemyLife.setSkewCenter(0, 0);    
    enemyLife.setText("Score: "+ captainLives);
     gameHUD.attachChild(enemyLife);
     
     
     camera.setHUD(gameHUD);
 }
 
 

 private void subtractFromLives()
 {
     lives  = lives -1;
     scoreText.setText("Lives: "+ lives);
     if (lives ==0)
     {
      SceneManager.getInstance().loadLossScene(engine);
      int finalScore = captainLives; //saves score when you run out of lives to be used in the comparator for the high scores.
     }
 }
 private void subtractFromCaptainLives()
 {
     captainLives  = captainLives +1;
     enemyLife.setText("Score: "+captainLives);
     if (captainLives ==0)
     {
      SceneManager.getInstance().loadWinScene(engine);
      
     } 
 }
 


 private void createPhysics()
 {
     physicsWorld = new FixedStepPhysicsWorld(20, new Vector2(0, -17), false); 
     registerUpdateHandler(physicsWorld);
 }
 
 @Override
 public void createScene()
 {
  resourcesManager.gMusic.play();
  
  //captainLives=3;
  lives = resourcesManager.number_lives;
  captainLives = resourcesManager.enemy_lives;
     createBackground();
     createHUD();
     createPhysics();
     createPlayer();
     createCaptain();
     createAETimeHandler(2);
      
 }


 
 private void createPlayer()
 {
  player = new Player(400,300, vbom,camera, physicsWorld)
  {

   @Override
   public void onDie() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
   }
   
  };
  final long[] PLAYER_ANIMATE = new long[] { 100, 100, 100 };
  player.animate(PLAYER_ANIMATE);
  this.attachChild(player);
 }
 
 private void createCaptain()
 {
  captain = new Captain(480,150, vbom,camera, physicsWorld)
  {

   @Override
   public void onDie() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
   }
   
   
   
   
  };
  final long[] PLAYER_ANIMATE = new long[] { 100, 100, 100 };
  captain.animate(PLAYER_ANIMATE);
  this.attachChild(captain);
 }
 
 private void createCrab()
 {
  int xpos = (int)(695*Math.random());
  crab = new Crab(xpos,0, vbom,camera, physicsWorld)
  {


   @Override
   protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed)
   {
    if (player.collidesWith(this))
    {
     subtractFromLives();
     float x = player.getX();
     float y = player.getY();
     crab.detachSelf();
     briefExplosion(x,y);
     collisionCheck=1;
     
    }
   }
   @Override
   public void onDie() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(collisionCheck==0)
    {
     crab.detachSelf();
    }
    
   }
   
  };
  this.attachChild(crab);
  collisionCheck=0;
  
 }
 GameScene scene = this;
 
 private void briefExplosion(float x, float y)
 {
  explosion = new Sprite(x, y, resourcesManager.explosion_region, vbom);
  scene.attachChild(explosion);
  flag = 0;
  
 }
 private void briefExplosion2(float x, float y)
 {
  explosion2 = new Sprite(x, y, resourcesManager.explosion2_region, vbom);
  scene.attachChild(explosion2);
  flag3 = 0;
  
 }
 
 private void briefHeart(float x, float y)
 {
  heart = new Sprite(x, y, resourcesManager.heart_region, vbom);
  scene.attachChild(heart);
  flag2 = 0;
  
 }
 
 private void createBomb()
 {
  int xpos = (int)(750*Math.random());
  bomb = new Bomb(xpos,0, vbom,camera, physicsWorld)
  {


   @Override
   protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed)
   {
    if (player.collidesWith(this))
    {
     subtractFromCaptainLives();
     float x = captain.getX();
     float y = captain.getY();
     bomb.detachSelf();
     briefExplosion2(x,y);
     collisionCheck=1;
    }
   }
   @Override
   public void onDie() {
    if(collisionCheck==0)
    {
     subtractFromLives();
     float x  = (float) (Math.random()*800);
     float y = 425;
     bomb.detachSelf();
     briefExplosion2(x,y);
    }
    
   }
   
  };
  this.attachChild(bomb);
  collisionCheck=0;
  
 }
 
 private void createPrincess()
 {
  int xpos = (int)(730*Math.random());
  princess = new Princess(xpos,0, vbom,camera, physicsWorld)
  {


   @Override
   protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed)
   {
    if (player.collidesWith(this))
    {
     float x = player.getX();
     float y = player.getY();
     princess.detachSelf();
     briefHeart(x,y);
     collisionCheck=1;
    }
   }
   @Override
   public void onDie() {
    if(collisionCheck==0)
    {
     subtractFromLives();
     princess.detachSelf();
    }
    
   }
   
  };
  this.attachChild(princess);
  collisionCheck=0;
 }
 
    
    private void createBackground()
    {
     //setBackground(new Background(Color.BLUE));
        ParallaxBackground background = new ParallaxBackground(0, 0, 0);
        background.attachParallaxEntity(new ParallaxEntity(0, new Sprite(0, 0, resourcesManager.game_background_region, vbom)));
        setBackground(background);
        
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackKeyPressed()
    {
     SceneManager.getInstance().loadMenuScene(engine);
    }

    @Override
    public SceneType getSceneType()
    {
        return SceneType.SCENE_GAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void disposeScene()
    {
        camera.setHUD(null);
        camera.setCenter(400, 240);
        resourcesManager.gMusic.stop();

        // TODO code responsible for disposing scene
        // removing all game scene objects.
    }
    
    

 @Override
 public void onAccelerationAccuracyChanged(AccelerationData pAccelerationData)
 {
  

 }



 @Override
 public void onAccelerationChanged(AccelerationData pAccelerationData) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  player.setPosition(player.getX() + pAccelerationData.getX()*2,300);
  

     if(player.getX() < 0)   
     {
      player.setPosition(0,300);
      
     }
     if(player.getX() > 550)   
     {
      player.setPosition(550,300);
      
     }
 }

 private boolean firstTouch = false;

 
    
 private void createAETimeHandler(float mEffectSpawnDelay)
    {
        TimerHandler spriteTimerHandler2;
  this.engine.registerUpdateHandler(spriteTimerHandler2 = new TimerHandler(mEffectSpawnDelay,true, new ITimerCallback()
        {                      
            @Override
            public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler)
            {
                 int i = (int)(Math.random()*10);
                 if( flag == 0)
                 {
                 explosion.detachSelf();
                 flag = 1;
                 }
                 if (flag2 == 0)
                 {
                  heart.detachSelf();
                  flag2 = 1;
                 }
                 if (flag3 == 0)
                 {
                  explosion2.detachSelf();
                  flag3 = 1;
                 }
                 if( i < 3)
                 {
                  createPrincess();
                 }
                 else if(i>3 && i<7)
                 {
                  createBomb();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                  createCrab();
                 }
             }
         }));
 }
 String FILENAME = "High_Scores";
 String string = "Arrggg";

 FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 fos.write(string.getBytes());
 fos.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

openFileOutput is a function on Context, and your class is not a context.  Either pass one in, or open it in another way.